# Selenium: How to switch to tab without focusing?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver

I'm using the Java Selenium and Chrome webdriver on Windows 10. I like to have a GUI up for debugging purposes, but my code keeps bringing the browser into focus. Specifically, lines like

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
```

will bring the automated Chrome browser into focus, taking me away from checking my e-mail etc. This is true regardless of whether I'm currently looking on Chrome or another browser.

How can I get Selenium to "silently" focus on a new tab (or window etc) so I can do something while my code runs? This is sort of like the issue reported here: [How can I bring Chrome browser to focus when running a Selenium test using ChromeDriver on Mac?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16428/how-can-i-bring-chrome-browser-to-focus-when-running-a-selenium-test-using-chrom), except I want to create the unfocused behavior that that user is trying to change.

Comment: run it in headless mode

Comment: Yes, I can use headless once I finish the code. But it's difficult while I'm writing it I need to see what's going on.